# JavaScript function altering width of div broke media screens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I successfully created a JavaScript function to simulate a "zoom-in" effect on a div when my webpage loads on start. This function broke the scaling of media screens. I understand why it broke, however, I am unsure of how to reformat to fix it.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#zoom-box').animate({
        width:'600px',
        height:'250px',
        top:'0',
        left:'0',
        }, 500);
    });
```

I know width:600px is too large for the media screen... however I am unsure how to override this. I tried maxWidth but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to see if it solves your problem?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    $('#zoom-box').animate({
    width: w,
    height:'250px',
    top:'0',
    left:'0',
    }, 500);
 });
```

Comment: this did not fix the media screen issue. i'm frustrated i cant use max-width, this is what fixed it before I tried adding this dynamic js stuff

Comment: if `max-width` was working before, then  you can try it here too. add `maxWidth : '100%',` or some other value that suits your need.

Comment: i thought the same. but for some reason it does not. maxWidth breaks the entire box..... width: '100%' fixes the media screen but it does not give as nice of an effect. I can play around with it from here! thanks :)

Comment: You should check if any other code is messing around with this `div` or not. In your `js` file(s) or any other plugins etc.